# What's the most highest ampere when PR2 comsume the most when charging?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to calculus ampere which PR2 need the highest?

What action will cause PR2 consume the most power?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40734/what%27s-the-most-highest-ampere-when-pr2-comsume-the-most-when-charging?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can find some information here in paragraph 1.2.4.
http://pr2support.willowgarage.com/wiki/PR2%20Modularity/Specs
And here the current per joint:
http://pr2support.willowgarage.com/wiki/PR2%20Manual/Chapter8

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2012-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1